# WPF Material Design how to change icon and press color of ComboBox icon?

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm using WPF .NET 7 and Material Design for WPF

How do I easily change the icon and press color of the ComboBox icon?

I want to replace the current icon with "ChevronDown" from Material Design Icons

```xml
<materialDesign:PackIcon Width="15" Height="15" Foreground="{StaticResource Foreground}" Kind="ChevronDown" />
```

This is the ComboBox. The current icon is circled
[ComboBox with White Triangle Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18vBV.png)

This is the ComboBox when the popup is open and you press+hold on it. How do I disable to purple color of the icon and always keep it white?
[ComboBox with Purple Triangle Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mGOA.png)

Here is a video for more visual info on what's happening
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zL3Rs6rCEM

Here is my GitHub repo
https://github.com/ZehsTeam/PhasmophobiaDiscordRPC

This is my ComboBox code

```xml
<ComboBox
    x:Name="LobbyTypeComboBox"
    Height="30"
    IsEnabled="True"
    SelectionChanged="LobbyTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged"
    Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxDefault}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Public" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Private" />
</ComboBox>
```

If anyone has a solution, how do I implement it into my application resources resource dictionary?

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="PhasmophobiaDiscordRPC.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Converters;assembly=MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf"
    xmlns:internal="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Internal;assembly=MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PhasmophobiaDiscordRPC"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;assembly=MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf"
    >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <materialDesign:BundledTheme
                    BaseTheme="Dark"
                    PrimaryColor="DeepPurple"
                    SecondaryColor="Lime" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesign3.Defaults.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!--  Colors  -->
            <Color x:Key="Colors.Foreground">#F2F3F5</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Colors.Foreground2">#B5BAC1</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Colors.Background">#36393e</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Colors.Background2">#282b30</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Colors.Background3">#1e2124</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Colors.Background4">#424549</Color>

            <!--  Brushes  -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground" Color="{StaticResource Colors.Foreground}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Foreground2" Color="{StaticResource Colors.Foreground2}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background" Color="{StaticResource Colors.Background}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background2" Color="{StaticResource Colors.Background2}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background3" Color="{StaticResource Colors.Background3}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background4" Color="{StaticResource Colors.Background4}" />

            <!--  ComboBox  -->
            <Style
                x:Key="ComboBoxDefault"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}"
                TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,5,10,5" />
                <Setter Property="materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Setter Property="materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Foreground}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I was not able to easily find a way to change the icon using Material Design Icons
I was not able to figure out how to keep the icon white at all times.

Comment: The triangle arrow is hardcoded in the template. You will have to create your own custom template to be able to replace it. There is property or similar that you can simply set to change it.